# Dont accept Null Values to store into an array

Tags: java, arrays, null

How do I need to code so that the array token[] doesn't take the null values read? The code is as follows.

```
String[] token = new String[0];
String opcode;
String strLine="";
String str="";
    try{
        // Open and read the file
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("a.txt");

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));

        //Read file line by line and storing data in the form of tokens
        if((strLine = br.readLine()) != null){

                token = strLine.split(" |,");//// split w.r.t spaces and ,  

  // what do I need to code, so that token[] doesnt take null values

            }
            }
        in.close();//Close the input stream
    }
```

Comment: Hint: `.split(str)` returns an array of `tokens`.

Comment: You need to tell us more about this question. `split` doesn't return `null` as array values. In worst case it will create empty string like `""` or it can return array with only one element containing original String if no match for `split` argument will be found. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: The way you have delimiters set to <space> <vertical-bar> and <comma> a line like `a,,c, ,d` would return a, c and d only.

Comment: Just a heads up, if you want to split over a pipe character, you need to escape it (`.split(" \\|,")`).  `split()` expects a Regex string.

Comment: Please don't use DataInputStream to read a text file. You don't need it so please remove it as people might copy this code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set `null` values into elements of array. If you want the token to prevent `null` values then you should check it first before assignment. But in your code the `token` array accepts only one element at index 0. If you need to set many elements consider to use `List`. And what you've assigned is just overridden by the other array returned by the `split`.

```
String[] token = strLine.split(" |,");
if(token!= null && token.lingth >0){

  // use the array
```

Answer (score 0):

An object oriented way to handle this is to make a new class that encapsulates the `token` array.  Give this class a way to set and get elements.  The set method will throw an exception if a null is passed in.

```
public void setElement(int index, String element) {
    if (element == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    //...
}
```

In your case since you're not creating the `token` array, you'd populate your new class from it:

```
for each t in token
   myEncapsulation.setElement(loopCount, t);
```

This is pseudo code of course.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: 
I'm not really sure what your question is about, maybe you should add some details.

Anyway, from the returns section of split method javadoc:

> **Returns**:
>
> > the array of strings computed by splitting this string around matches of the given regular expression

Here is a link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String, int)

So the split method always returns a String array. If the passed regexp doesn't match it will return a String array with just one element: the original String.

This line:

```
if(strLine.split(" |,")!=null){
```

Should become like this:

```
String[] splittedStrLine = strLine.split(" |,");
if(splittedStrLine.length > 1) {
```

Hope this helps